# Heroku git repo has no references. How to initialize

Tags: git, heroku

I set up a new dyno at Heroku and have a releasescript that I want to use to deploy code.
This script runs the following command to list references at Heroku and kills the script if none exist:

```
git ls-remote my-project
597c8ac33f6b4f77e0b89a88b824986d059890ef    HEAD
597c8ac33f6b4f77e0b89a88b824986d059890ef    refs/heads/master
```

When running this script on the new dyno that I just setup I don't see any references. Should these be setup automatically when creating the dyno? I just get an empty reply.

Answer (score 1):

The new repository is empty. It doesn't have any commits so there are no branches.

You have to push something to the repo to add commits and create references.